# Sum of total sales values for a given year

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following example I get the sum of sales per car with the following query:

```
id | cars
1    Ford
2    BMW
3    Fiat

id | id_cars | sales | sale_date
1       1        20      2016
2       1        30      2017
3       2        25      2017
4       2        35      2016
5       3        15      2017


SELECT car.id, car.cars, SUM(sal.sales) AS value_sales
FROM cars car
LEFT JOIN sales_cars sal  ON  car.id = sal.id_cars
GROUP BY car.id
```

If I use the following segment in the query, I get only the registrations of cars that have sales in 2017, but that's not what I want.

```
AND YEAR(sal.sale_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

What I want to achieve is to get all records of cars sold (as in the previous query) but only the sum of the values of the current year.

For example : **1 | Ford | 30**   and not **50** (2016 and 2017)

What is the correct way to do this query?

**EDITED**

Get current year and total years (following juergen answer):

```
SELECT car.id, car.cars, 
   SUM(case when YEAR(sal.sale_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
            then sal.sales 
            else 0 
       end) AS value_sales
   SUM(sal.sales) AS value_sales_total_years
FROM cars car
LEFT JOIN sales_cars sal  ON  car.id = sal.id_cars
GROUP BY car.id
```

Comment: Do you still want to show 2016 data?

Comment: Thanks vol7ron. In my case, on the client side, only the total of the values for the current year will be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional SUM()

```
SELECT car.id, car.cars, 
       SUM(case when YEAR(sal.sale_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                then sal.sales 
                else 0 
           end) AS value_sales
FROM cars car
LEFT JOIN sales_cars sal  ON  car.id = sal.id_cars
GROUP BY car.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Conditions on the first table in a `LEFT JOIN` go in the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on subsequent tables go in the `ON` clause.  So the best way to write this query is:

```
SELECT car.id, car.cars, SUM(sal.sales) AS value_sales
FROM cars car LEFT JOIN
     sales_cars sal
     ON  car.id = sal.id_cars AND YEAR(sal.sale_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY car.id;
```

For cars that have no sales in 2017, the `LEFT JOIN` will produce `NULL` values for `sal.sale_date`.  Your `WHERE` clause filters out such records.  The `ON` does not because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff for the example and  the detailed explanation. Much simpler this way

Comment: If I want to get the totals sales for the current year and simultaneity the overall totals (every year), how to do with conditions in ON clause? I edited my post with a solution with conditions following juregen sugestion, but for training I would like to know how to do it with the ON clause or otherwise.